# Double integration over a Region $D$ enclosed by circle and lines

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> If $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\geq 1, 0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq 1\}$, then find $$\iint_{D}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dA$$

What i try: I have draw diagram of region $D$

[image]

Using polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$

And $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dA=rdrd\theta$

So Integral $$I=\iint_{D}\frac{r}{r^4}dr\,d\theta=\iint_{D}\frac{1}{r^3}dr\,d\theta$$

I do not understand how can I set limit for $r$ and $\theta$. Help me please. Thanks

Comment: The graph that you provided is a great way to notice that the angle $\theta$ varies within $0$ and $\pi/2$. What about the radius? It varies from the circle $r=1$ to the two lines, expressed in polar coordinates. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment:

Notice that when $\theta\in[0,\pi/4]$, $r$ varies between the circle ($r=1$) and the line $x=1$, which in polar coordinates is described by $r=1/\cos\theta$.
On the same manner, when $\theta\in[\pi/4,\pi/2],$ $r$ varies between $r=1$ and the line $y=1$, which in polar coordinates is given by $r=1/\sin\theta$. Therefore you are looking for the solution of the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{1}^{1/\cos\theta}r^{-3}drd\theta+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{1}^{1/\sin\theta}r^{-3}drd\theta$$

Comment: Or use symmetry and just double one of these integrals.